# Column alignment in Grid

Tags: grid-layouts, alignment

How can I align elements in column when `SpanFromAbove` is used?

Using the example given in documentation for `Grid`

```
Grid[Table[RandomChoice[{SpanFromLeft, SpanFromAbove,
Item[RandomInteger[1000],Background -> Hue[RandomReal[], .2, .9]]}], {20}, {12}],
Frame -> All, Alignment -> Center]
```

results:

[image]

The `SpanFromLeft` row elements are centered but not the ones from `SpanFromAbove` column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
Alignment -> {Center, Center}
```